# How do you decide what an acceptable p-value is for a K-S test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Let's say you're thinking about running a hypothesis test (like a t-test) on some data that requires your sample to be normally distributed. You decide on a 95% CI and you run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to find out if the sample fits a normal distribution.

Unlike with your hypothesis test, which you've already decided needs to have a p-value of less than .05, with a K-S test you're looking for a high p-value that indicates a high likelihood that the difference between the distributions is due to random chance.

It seems intuitive that in this case you would only accept p-values for your K-S test that are over .95, since it would establish the absence of a difference between distributions using a standard that is congruent with the one you chose for establishing statistical significance.

Is this a best practice, or are there situations where you would accept greater or lesser uncertainty with your K-S test than with your hypothesis test?

How do you decide what an acceptable p-value is for a K-S test?

Comment: 1. "indicating a high probability that your distribution fits a certain shape" -- that's not a correct interpretation of a p-value. 2. Setting your p-value very high will mean you'd almost always reject the hypothesis for data generated from exactly the null model. 3. I'd also say that formal hypothesis tests of distributional models (at any p-value) are usually not a good idea (and often far from "best practice", particularly when testing distributional assumptions for some procedure)

Comment: Per your comment - just edited for clarity.

Comment: KS is a hypothesis test, so I don't follow what you're trying to do, nor do I see how a confidence interval comes into play. A confidence interval should be about some statistic. In the case of KS, that statistic is the maximum vertical distance between the CDFs, and you could form a confidence interval for that value, sure.

Comment: @les Oh, I should add 5. For the Kolmogorov-Smirnov you're not testing "shape" but the exact distributional form, including all parameters specified (unless you mean something like Lilliefors test, which is not distribution free. The Wikipedia page [for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) needs work, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my question again. I know about K-S being useful for testing other distribution shapes. What I want to know is how do you decide what an acceptable p-value is for a K-S test. I would welcome any answers to this effect, as I haven't found any good explanations anywhere.

Comment: Your comment suggests you misunderstood the point being made in 5, but I'll attempt to address it as part of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Size of p-value from KS test is not a proper measure to check the validity of t-test.

Imagine that the true underlying distribution is not a normal distribution but very close to a normal distribution (e.g., having a very tiny bump on right tail). If your sample size is small, you cannot detect this small deviation so your p-value is probably large. However, if you collect more and more data, your data have more power to detect even such a small deviation, and thus p-value is getting smaller and smaller. Therefore, if your sample size is large, even if p-value seems to be small (e.g., ~0.1), the underlying distribution can be very close to a normal distribution and thus t-test can yield a statistically valid result. (In fact, t-test is robust to the violation of normality assumption once the true underlying distribution is symmetric, see Efron, Bradley. "Student's t-test under symmetry conditions." or Martins, Joäo Paulo. "Student t-statistic distribution for non-Gaussian populations.")

Therefore, instead of using KS test, you should check the histogram of your data and Q-Q plot. Also, you can also use distribution-robust testing procedures (e.g., permutation test, concentration inequality based test) together to see whether these distribution-robust tests give you the same answer as t-test.

Answer (score 2):

The t test works quite well for many samples that are not exactly normal. You are correct that some care is required in order to use the t test appropriately. However, you seem to be asking the wrong questions about the wrong procedures. I hope the following discussion will help you get onto a more useful track.

**Moderately large samples.** In many circumstances, a t test can be used even if the data are not
from a normal distribution. If the sample size is moderately large, then you
mainly want to make sure that the sample is not strongly skewed---say
with many outliers on one side of the mean.

***A gamma sample.*** For example, suppose you have $n = 40$ observations from  a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution): specifically, $\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=10, \text{rate}=0.2).$
Then the population mean is $\mu = 50.$

```
set.seed(810)
x = round(rgamma(40, 10, .2), 2);  x
 [1]  65.05  48.21  55.54  35.91  53.89  44.36  61.77  69.20  32.15  52.44
[11]  64.63  19.08  68.95  66.05  37.58  50.72  44.65  53.87  55.88  26.27
[21]  92.36  54.29  46.94  37.97  50.64  48.63  81.01  51.25  44.91  56.09
[31]  28.16  57.92  38.68  41.39 107.56  37.29  30.94  53.33  73.54  38.18
```

A data summary hints at right-skewness because the sample mean is a little larger than the sample median, and because the maximum is a lot farther from
the center than the minimum is.

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  19.08   38.55   50.98   51.93   58.88  107.56
```

The Shapiro-Wilk test is one of the better choices for a formal test of normality. The P-value $0.08 > 0.05,$ so normality is not (quite) rejected.

```
 shapiro.test(x)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

 data:  x
 W = 0.9507, p-value = 0.08013
```

A boxplot shows moderate skewness with a couple of outliers on the high side.

```
 boxplot(x, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
```

[image]

A histogram (left panel) shows a 'tail' toward the right. A gamma density curve (solid) seems to fit better than a normal density curve (dotted), but with only 40 observations, neither fit is very good. Also points on a normal probability plot (right panel) bend away from a straight line, Both plots show signs of moderate
skewness.

[image]

***Testing a hypothesis.*** In a real experiment, you would not know the value of $\mu.$ Suppose you want to test $H_0: \mu = 58$
against $H_a: \mu < 58.$ (Maybe you have been told that bad things happen if $\mu$ is too small. You can see that $\bar X = 51.93,$ so you'd like to do a formal test to see if such a sample mean is a credible warning.)

We have not shown that the sample is inconsistent with normality, but there are clues that the population may not be normal. If we *knew* the data are from a gamma distribution, there might be better options that a t test for our
our test whether $\mu > 58,$ but most statisticians would feel comfortable using a t test, which has a reputation of behaving well when data are not exactly normal. In this case, we rejected $H_0: \mu = 58$ with P-value 0.0176.
However, the accompanying confidence interval indicates that we would not
have rejected $H_0 = 56.$

```
t.test(x, mu=58, alte="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = -2.1832, df = 39, p-value = 0.01755
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 58
95 percent confidence interval:
   -Inf 56.615
sample estimates:
mean of x 
   51.932
```

Thus we 'got by' using a t test in this case. Because we simulated the data
we *know* that the data are not normal, but in a real experiment we would not
have been sure.

**Simulating the true significance level.** For the long run, we are interested in the actual level of the test. We
intend to test at the 5% level, but if the data aren't normal, then we can't
be sure of that. To investigate this, we can take many samples of size $n=40$ from $\mathsf{Gamma}(10, 20/58),$ which has $\mu=58,$ and see how often $H_0: \mu = 58$ is (wrongly) rejected.  The result is that the true significance
level is very close to 5%, as planned.

```
pv = replicate(10^6, t.test(rgamma(40,10/58,.2), mu=58, alt="le")$p.val)
mean(pv <- .05)
[1] 0.05
```

**Simulating the power.** It is also of interest to know the probability of (valid) rejection, if the true population mean is as low as $\mu = 50.$ That probability is the 'power' of the test against the alternative $\mu = 50.$ Simulation shows that the power is above 90%.

```
pv = replicate(10^6, t.test(rgamma(40,10,.2), mu=58, alt="le")$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.914989
```

We have seen that for the particular kind of non-normality in our example, the t test performs very well.

**Smaller samples.** If is smaller than in our example, then it is even more difficult to determine from the sample whether the population is normal. For moderate departures from normality, the t test often works well.  One takes the same precautions to
make sure that departure from normal (if any) is 'moderate':  trying a formal normality test in case it shows trouble, and informally looking at boxplots and other data summaries to see if there are warnings of severe skewness. (Formal normality tests are almost useless for very small samples, so one is fussier about informal criteria. In a sample of size 10, we would not want to see two outliers on the same side of center.)

**Alternatives to a t test.** In case of serious doubt that the population is nearly normal, one might choose a rank-based nonparametric test such as the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, or some kind of permutation test that does not assume normality. These alternative
tests have their own assumptions, which should be checked to the extent possible.